# Angular dar formato a fecha mediante pipe en un databing en un input

Tags: html, angular, webforms

Estoy intentando crear un **pipe** que auto-formatee el **date** que le va a llegar. Y pase de esto : `2019-04-11T00:00:00.000Z` a esto otro : `2019-04-11`

Estoy **intentando** algo como :

```
 <input type="datetime" class="form-control" name="fecha_nacimiento"  [(ngModel)]="user.fecha_nacimiento | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd'" (change)="editable = true">
```

El **input** tiene que ser de **datetime** ya que es lo que le llega

Comment: relacionada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular

Comment: Usa simplemente <input  [value]="user.fecha_nacimiento | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd">

Answer (score 0):

De la [documentación de Angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-statements)

> ### Template statements
>
> A template statement responds to an event raised by a binding target such as an element, component, or directive. You'll see template statements in the event binding section, appearing in quotes to the right of the = symbol as in (event)="statement".
>
> ```
> <button (click)="deleteHero()">Delete hero</button>
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> However, certain JavaScript syntax is not allowed:
>
> - new
> - increment and decrement operators, ++ and --
> - operator assignment, such as += and -=
> - the bitwise operators | and &
> - the template expression operators

Traducción (aproximada):

### Sentencias en plantillas

Una sentencia en una plantilla responde a un evento asociado a un elemento, componente o directiva. Puedes ver estas sentencias entre comillas a la derecha de un símbolo =, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<button (click)="deleteHero()">Delete hero</button>
```

(...)

Sin embargo, cierta sintaxis de JavaScript no está permitida:

- new
- operadores ++ y --
- operadores de bit | y &
- **operadores de expresiones** de plantillas.

Por tanto no puedes usar un *pipe* dentro de una sentencia asociada a un evento.
La solución es separar en dos partes la expresión:

```
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" name="fecha_nacimiento"  
    [ngModel]="user.fecha_nacimiento | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd'"
    (ngModelChange)="user.fecha_nacimiento=$event" (change)="editable = true">
```

Comment: Y como podria controlar el evento `(ngModelChange)="user.fecha_nacimiento=$event"` porque me interesa que si no es una fecha compatible no aparezca un boton, entonces necesito saber controlar ese **evento** como podria hacerlo ?

Comment: Usa una función: `(ngModelChange)="setFechaNacimiento($event)"` y comprueba ahí lo que necesites

Answer (score 0):

Tal como mencionado en el comentario una forma es simple:

```
<input [value]="user.fecha_nacimiento | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd">
```

en caso de añadir el type="date" a tu input entonces tienes que formatear la fecha antes de añadir:

```
const hoy = new Date();
    this.today = formatDate(hoy, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'es')
    console.log(this.today);
```

y en el input:

```
<input type="date" [value]="today">
```

Si es Angular formatDate se encuentra en

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
```